# How to understand the bias term in language model head (when we tie the word embeddings)?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, language-model

I was learning the masked language modeling codebase in Huggingface Transformers. Just a question to understand the language model head.

Here at the final linear layer where we project hidden size to vocab size (https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/f2fbe4475386bfcfb3b83d0a3223ba216a3c3a91/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L685-L702).

```py
self.decoder = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, config.vocab_size, bias=False)
self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(config.vocab_size))
self.decoder.bias = self.bias
```

We set the `bias` term to zero at the moment. And later when we initialize the weight, we tie the weight of the linear layer and the word embedding.

But we don't do such a thing for the bias term. I wonder how we can understand that and why we want to initialize the bias term as a zero vector.

https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L1060-L1079

```py
    def tie_weights(self):
        """
        Tie the weights between the input embeddings and the output embeddings.
        If the `torchscript` flag is set in the configuration, can't handle parameter sharing so we are cloning the
        weights instead.
        """
        if getattr(self.config, "tie_word_embeddings", True):
            output_embeddings = self.get_output_embeddings()
            if output_embeddings is not None:
                self._tie_or_clone_weights(output_embeddings, self.get_input_embeddings())

        if getattr(self.config, "is_encoder_decoder", False) and getattr(self.config, "tie_encoder_decoder", False):
            if hasattr(self, self.base_model_prefix):
                self = getattr(self, self.base_model_prefix)
            self._tie_encoder_decoder_weights(self.encoder, self.decoder, self.base_model_prefix)

        for module in self.modules():
            if hasattr(module, "_tie_weights"):
                module._tie_weights()
```

My understanding:

1. Because the final linear weight accepts the hidden representations that have been transformed by several feed-forward layers. We might not be able to match them exactly, we need the bias term to somehow regularize them.

As I'm not sure my understanding is accurate, I would like to seek your opinions.